# How to extract overlapping geometries within a single GeoDataFrame using Python?

Tags: python, gis, geopandas, overlap

I updated the geometries of large GeoDataFrame containing points geometries by using [`geopandas.Geoseries.buffer`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.buffer.html). I need to create two GeoDataFrames from this buffered geometries:

- One with the overlapping polygons
- One with the isolated polygons

In QGIS I would use the [`Select by location`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#select-by-location) tool with the *`Overlap`*  geometric predicate. By comparing the buffer layer with itself, I would obtain a selection of overlapping entities and by inverting the selection I would obtain non overlapping entities.

In Python, I tried to loop within the geometries and compared each geometry to the DataFrame using [`geopandas.GeoSeries.overlaps`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.overlaps.html). This method works but takes a lot of time because of the loop. In QGIS it takes 40s to do the process, in python it took 1:20h.

Is there a way to do it as fast as QGIS ?

Here's an example of the code I used :

```
# Points buffer
points = gpd.read_file("path_to_my_layer.gpkg")
buffer = (
    points.copy()
) 
buffer.geometry = points.geometry.buffer(3)

# Overlaps check
overlaps_ids = np.array([], dtype=np.int64)
for geom in buffer.geometry:  # <-- This takes a lot of time
    overlaps = buffer.geometry.overlaps(geom)  # check overlapping features
    where_overlaps = np.where(overlaps == True)
    overlaps_ids = np.concatenate((overlaps_ids, where_overlaps[0]))
overlaps_ids = np.unique(overlaps_ids)  # list overlapping IDs

# Overlapping geometries extraction
buffer_overlaps = buffer.iloc[overlaps_ids]

# Non overlapping geometries extraction
buffer_no_overlaps = buffer.drop(overlaps_ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet should do the same as your sample script, but should be a lot faster because spatial indexes are used under the hood:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np

# Buffer
gdf = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("nybb"))
buffer = gdf.copy()
buffer.geometry = buffer.geometry.buffer(3)

# Overlaps check
intersecting_gdf = buffer.sjoin(buffer, predicate="intersects")
intersecting_gdf = intersecting_gdf.loc[
    intersecting_gdf.index != intersecting_gdf.index_right
]
overlaps_ids = np.unique(intersecting_gdf.index)  # list overlapping IDs
print(overlaps_ids)
```